# Windows Media Centre Download For Windows Home Basic

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center, media

How and from where can I download Windows Media Center for my laptop running Windows Home Basic  as it does not come pre installed with it. Help in this regard, if no any alternatives you would like to suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Home Basic doesn't include Media Center. Unfortunately, Media Centre is not available as a downloadable package either. You would need to install a version of Windows that already has it included(Home Premium, Professional, Ultimate, Enterprise).

A pretty good alternative would be XBMC. Its open-source and has a nice interface. http://xbmc.org